# the transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running same query in two different windows of the same server.
the only difference is : the query that is throwing above error has got 'index' on the temporary tables.

The query w/o index on temporary tables is working fine. Please explain how could index be a reason for this error?

Comment: In general this should not be the case unless you server do not have space crunch at temp db.

Comment: There is an active transaction. During a LOG BACKUP there is a long running transaction.

Comment: When there is an index, SQL-Server has to maintain it (check and update it if any data change). Those things take up resources and they are considered part of your transaction.

Comment: @DVT Thanks for your comment. it made me understand the error better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends from your query. SQL-Server has to maintain indexes during data changes. This can drives you in different time-waith events.

Try this: check on your two different SQL Server instances what's heppening exactly to your running session during query executon.
You can do this monitoring wait events creating a monitor sessions for a single SPID.

This is my complete procedure to this: http://zaboilab.com/sql-server-toolbox/monitoring-wait-events-of-a-single-session-or-query